# a function that works with array elements

Tags: c

I need to write a function that subtracts digits.
If user inputs 2345, the output should be 111 (5-4, 4-3, 3-2); another example would be 683, where the output should be 25 (3-8(abs value is taken), 8-6).

I have wrote the following code which works only when the size of the array is declared.

```
int subtraction(int arr[], int size) {
int sub = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
    sub = sub * 10 + abs(arr[i] - arr[i+1]);
}
return sub;
}
```

However, the number that the user inputs is random and can have various digits, so I don't know what limit to put in the for loop.

For example:

```
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 55, 56, 65, 135}, i;
    subtraction(arr, 6);
    for (i=0; i<6; i++)
         printf("%d ", arr[i]);
```

expected output: 0 0 0 1 1 22

The function is supposed to subtract the second-to-last digit from the last one, by the way , / from right to left / from a random number that the user inputs ; for example if the input is 5789, the output is supposed to be 211 (9-8, 8-7, 7-5); if user inputs a negative number, the program should take it's absolute value and then do the subtracting. If user input is a one digit number the result should be 0.

The function I wrote only works when the size of the array is declared. I don't know how to make it work when the size is undeclared (pointers and malloc are required I believe, as that's what I managed to find out by googling for ages, but unfortunately, I don't know how to do it).

please help?

Comment: let's see, you pass an array to a function, then, using the array you just passed you update your `int sub` variable to reflect your calculation, the return `sub` you do nothing with the result value, then print the array you never modified.

Comment: You seem to expect your function to modify the array provided as its argument, but instead it returns its (scalar) result via a `return` statement, leaving the array unmodified.

Comment: Different problem, but note that taking the absolute value of the result of a subtraction is not the same as subtracting the absolute value of both operands.

Comment: And, I don't think the expected output of `0 0 0 1 1 22` at all matches the behavior you describe for an input of `1 2 55 56 65 135`. 135 - 65 is not 22, to start.

Comment: The function implementation seems designed to solve the problem for *one* number that has been pre-split into an array of single digits, but your example input and expected results seem to suppose that it will perform multiple computations such as you describe, handling each array element as an independent input.

Comment: And no, pointers do not save you from passing the _size_ (number of elements) of the array to a function, cause when you pass an array to a function it always decays to pointer, meaning your're actually passing a pointer to the first element of the array. and pointers do not keep track of the number of elements of the object they point to. whether the array is statically or dynamically allocated.

Comment: @PhilM actually it calculates each element individually (135 is 22 because 5-3 and 3-1 --> 22)

Comment: Split the problem. Write a function taking an `int` which substracts digit wise. Then write a function taking an array and size and do it for each element.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe it was confusing to put that there, those are just part of automated testing; the process should be simple – user inputs a number (which should be read as an array) and the function should subtract the digits as I described

Comment: Your array elements are independent of each other, you do not need other elements to calculate your current one, right?

Comment: @protagorus, "just automated testing" does not make sense.  The code you present is feeding different input to your function than what you describe, and apparently has different expectations of the function's behavior than you describe.  I don't see how there's an answer here different from "you're using the function wrongly."

Comment: @Osiris yep, each one is calculated individually - 55, 56, 65, 135 (5-5, 5-6, 6-5, 5-3 and 3-1 make 0, 1, 1, 22)

Comment: Then you should start with a function that calculates it for one `int`. After that you just need to loop over the array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Let me try to explain it again (ignoring the examples above): user inputs a number, for example 38279. the function should subtract the digits from that number (9-7, 7-2, 2-8, 8-3) and print the new number: 5652. that's about it. Those examples i put up there are just part of tests which are used to check if the function is working right, nothing more

Comment: @JennyT-Type this function works when the array has a defined size. the thing is, i don't know how to make it work when the array size if undefined. and i also don't know how to scan the elements without \n or any space between them (to input it just like 1345, without having to hit enter or space)

Comment: @Osiris how do i do it if i don't know the array size?

Comment: @protagorus, explaining what you want to achieve in comments does not solve the problems with this question.  I deduced early on what you want the function to do.  Although it *is* a problem that that's not clear from the question itself, it is even more a problem that it's unclear how you're actually calling the function and how you're actually observing the results you describe.  So please, edit the question to present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, as indeed is our usual expectation here.

Comment: @protagorus The question isn't very well formed; you imply that you want to know why your test is repeating your input numbers, and that was answered twice in these comments and once in an answer. What you appear to be asking in these comments are "how do I work with an array of unknown size" which has also been answered: "you don't". Can you rephrase the question incorporating the comments to clarify what you need done?

Comment: @JohnBollinger i understand, I'll edit it, sorry!

Comment: @SeanMonroe true, i didn't really phrase it right, I'm fixing it, sorry!

Comment: @protagorus by the way the output for 38279 is 2565 not 5652

Comment: @HeIs ohhh i actually forgot to clarify this! it's subtracting from right to left and reading the values ALSO from right to left (9-7=2, 7-2=5, 2-8=-6, 8-3=5; so from right to left it's 5652)

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually changing any values, here is the line you need to look at.

```
sub = sub * 10 + abs(arr[i] - arr[i+1]);
```

As you are printing the array you actually need to store the calculated value in the array again.

Comment: how does this answer the question ?

Comment: that part is actually working when user inputs both size and number. it returns the right value. the thing is, i don't know how to make it work when the size of the array is undefined (that's why those examples up there don't work)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int subtract(int n)
{
  int factor = 1;
  int total = 0;
  int lastPlace = n%10;
  n /= 10;
  while (n>0)
  {
      total += (factor * abs((n%10) - lastPlace));
      factor *= 10;
      lastPlace = n%10;
      n /= 10;
  } 
  return total;
}

void subtractArray(int* arr, unsigned int size)
{
  for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
  {
    if (arr[i] < 0)
      arr[i] = abs(arr[i]);
    arr[i] = subtract(arr[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 55, 56, 65, 135};
  int size = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);
  subtractArray(arr, size);
  for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
  {
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works!!!! Thank you so much for the time and effort you've put in the writing of the whole code!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that solve your problem :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *subtraction(int arr[], int size) 
{
    int *sub = calloc(sizeof(int*) , size), i = 0, rev;              //allocating memory 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {    
        rev = 0;
        arr[i] = abs(arr[i]);

        for (int a = 0; arr[i] != 0; arr[i] /= 10)
            rev = (rev * 10) + (arr[i] % 10);

        for (i; (rev / 10) != 0; rev /= 10)             //the loop ends when rev = 0
            sub[i] = ((sub[i] * 10) + abs( (rev % 10) - ((rev / 10) % 10) ));    //easy math => for example rev = 21 > sub[i] = (0 * 10) + ( (21 % 10) - ((21 / 10) %10)) = abs(1 - 2) = 1;
    }
    return sub;
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {-9533, 7, -19173}, i;
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  //size of arr
    int *sub = subtraction(arr, len);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)   //for test
        printf("%d ", sub[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

output for {1, 2, 55, 56, 65, 135}:

```
0 0 0 1 1 22
```

output for {987654321, 123456789, 111111111} :

```
11111111 11111111 0
```

output for {38279}:

```
5652
```

output for {-9533, 7, -19173}:

```
420 0 8864
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as for the *array of undefined size*. What you probably want is a **dynamically allocated array**.

Here we get the number of array elements based on user input, within limits, of course.
first we're gonna get the number from the user using `fgets()` which will give us a string, then we'll use `strtol()` to convert the number part to scalar (int). you can use `scanf("%d", &n)` if you want.

Then we can count the digits from that number, and that value will be the number of elements of our array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     //for strtol(), malloc() and NULL guaranteed
//you may also want to add 
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_STRLEN  12   // can hold all digits of INT_MAX plus '\0' and a posible, AND very likely, '\n'
#define DEC 10           // for strtol base argument

/*
 * I'm lending you my old get_n_dits() function that I used to count decimal digits.
 */
int get_n_dits(int dnum) {

    unsigned char stop_flag = 0;    //we'll use to signal we're done with the loop.

    int  num_dits = 1, dpos_mult = 1;  //num_dits start initialized as 1, cause we're pretty sure that we're getting a number with at least one digit
                                       //dpos_mult stands for digital position multiplier.
    int check_zresult;  //we'll check if integer division yields zero.

    /**
     * Here we'll iterate everytime (dnum / dpost_mult) results in a non-zero value, we don't care for the remainder though, at least for this use.
     * every iteration elevates dpost_mult to the next power of ten and every iteration yielding a non-zero result increments n_dits, once we get
     * the zero result, we increment stop_flag, thus the loop condition is no longer true and we break from the loop.
     */

    while(!stop_flag) {

        dpos_mult *= 10;
        check_zresult = dnum / dpos_mult;
        (check_zresult) ? num_dits++ : stop_flag++;
    }

    return num_dits;
} 


int main(void) {

    int num, ndits;                    //we'll still using int as per your code. you can check against INT_MAX if you want (defined in limits.h)
    int *num_array = NULL;      //let's not unintentionally play with an unitialized pointer.
    char *num_str = malloc(MAX_STRLEN);     //or malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STRLEN); if there's any indication that (sizeof(char) != 1)

    printf("please enter a number... please be reasonable... or ELSE!\n");
    printf(">>> ");
    if(!fgets(num_str, MAX_STRLEN, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading from STDIN stream.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    num = (int)strtol(num_str, NULL, DEC);  //convert the string from user input to scalar.
    if(!num) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: no number found on input.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ndits = get_n_dits(num);

    if(ndits <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Aw, crap!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("number of digits: %d\n", ndits);

    num_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * ndits);        //now we have our dynamically allocated array.

    return 0;

}
```